# R and 'plm' package: how to use lapply to loop through columns of a 'pdata.frame' object

Tags: r, apply, plm

I am using the 'plm' package to carry out some simulations. I need to carry out a "within" transformation on all variables in a given dataset. A 'for' loop works fine, while the 'lapply' version does not. I create the dataset as:

```
library(plm)
data<- data.frame(replicate(10, runif(100)))
pdata <- pdata.frame(data, index=10)
varlist <- names(pdata)[names(pdata)!=("id") & names(pdata)!="time"]
```

I can run a 'within' transformation on a single variable, e.g.:`Within(pdata$X1)` works. Or I can run a 'for' loop, which also works:

```
pdata.with2 <- pdata[, varlist]
for(i in 1:ncol(pdata.with2)){
    pdata.with2[,i]= Within(pdata[,i])
}
```

The lappy version fails:

```
pdata.with  <-  lapply(pdata[, varlist], Within)
```

and gives the error: "Error in UseMethod("Within") : 
  no applicable method for 'Within' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')". It seems as the way 'lapply' loops through the variables misses some of the attributes that make the columns of the class "pseries" "numeric". As an example

```
class(pdata$X1)
```

gives

```
[1] "pseries" "numeric"
```

while

```
lapply(pdata[, varlist], class)
```

gives

```
$X1
[1] "numeric"
...
```

My question: is there a way to use 'lapply' on a 'pdata.frame' object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct that `lapply` accesses the `pdata.frame` in a different way which is due to the fact how a `pdata.frame` currently is defined (same is true for `with()`) and you can see that in the way you have shown by looking at the class attribute in two diffent ways.

If you want to use `lapply` you can coerce to a list first by the pdata.frame method for `as.list` (`plm:::as.list.pdata.frame`) with the option `keep.attributes` like this:

```
res <- data.frame(lapply(as.list(pdata[ , varlist], keep.attributes = TRUE), Within))
all.equal(pdata.with2, res, check.attributes = FALSE)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work for me. I get the same error message. I tried

Comment: `res <- data.frame(lapply(as.list(pdata[ , varlist], keep.attributes = TRUE), class))
res` I still get "numeric" attributes only. My version of plm is 1.5-12
Sorry for the 'split' comment, I am new to stack overflow, and still a little clumsy

Comment: I upgraded `plm`to 1.6-6, and now everything works. In 1.5-12 the `as.list` method was not defined. Thanks again for your help